# Can't see MySQL BIT field value when using SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, bit

`my_table` contains the `enabled` field which is defined as: `enabled BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.

This table has multiple rows with `enabled = b'0'`, and multiple rows with `enabled = b'1'`.

However, both this:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE enabled = b'0';
```

and this:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE enabled = b'1';
```

show blank in the `enabled` column:

```
+----+---------+
| id | enabled |
+----+---------+
|  1 |         |
|  2 |         |
+----+---------+
```

Why is that? How could I see the value of the `enabled` field?

---

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

---

Comment: Why are you using `BIT` instead of `BOOLEAN`?  Will you need to store more than one flag in that column?

Comment: Thats odd. I can't reproduce that. Works [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64482/1)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The reason why you can't see it in terminal is because bit values are non printable characters.

Lets insert following values:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`ID`, `enabled`)
VALUES (1,b'1'),(2,b'0');
```

Then select them to file:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/my_table.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

First lets view our `/tmp/my_table.txt`file as plain text:

> "1"," "
>   "2"," "

and then in hex view:

> 22 31 22 2C 22 **01** 22 0A 22 32 22 2C 22 **00** 22 0A

To be able to see those values you can simply `CAST` them in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT id, CAST(enabled AS UNSIGNED) AS enabled FROM my_table
```

And that will produce the following output:

```
+----+---------+
| id | enabled |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |       0 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: how to enable/view this when using `select * from my_table`?

Comment: For anyone comming after, you can't do this on a select * from thetable. You need to list all fields you want.

Answer (score 33):

Another way you can do it is

```
SELECT enabled+0 from my_table
```

Answer (score 30):

the simplest way is `ORD` function:

```
SELECT ORD(`enabled`) AS `enabled` FROM `my_table`
```

Answer (score 7):

> Bit values are returned as binary values. To display them in printable form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN().

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html

Comment: SELECT BIN(b'1'); returns 0

Comment: Usage: `SELECT BIN(my_column) FROM my_table` or `SELECT my_column+0 FROM my_table`

Answer (score 2):

Use `HEX()`

Like:
`SELECT id, HEX(enabled) AS enabled FROM my_table`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `SELECT enabled&1 from my_table`.

Answer (score 0):

to convert a bit field value to a human readable string, use the built-in [EXPORT_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_export-set) function, the simple example to convert a column of type bit(1) to a "Y" or "N" value would be

```
EXPORT_SET(column, 'Y', 'N')
```

You could also convert a bit(8) value to binary representation of the byte

```
EXPORT_SET(column, '1', '0', '', 8)
```