# What value could I insert into a bit type column?

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean, bit

[image: statue type][image: the situation]I am trying to insert or edit the bit value to "0" or "1", but either returns me a blank.

Could someone tells me how to insert the value in it?

Also, Is that possible to not use bit type but Boolean? I see there's a Boolean type in the list of types

Thanks

Hi, I have uploaded the picture, the cell in the table is blank, but I have tried several times, add, update, all take effect, but cell keeps blank...

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: And what database are you using?

Comment: Hi @FreshPrinceOfSO, I am using PHPMyAdmin by Hostgator

Comment: @Adrian, I am using PHPMyAdmin by Hostgator

Comment: PHPMyAdmin isn't a database, it's an interface. If you're using PMA, your database is MySQL. Also, it's not made by Hostgator (is that your hosting company?), it's a widely-used open-source project: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally speaking, for `boolean` or `bit` data types, you would use `0` or `1` like so:

```
UPDATE tbl SET bitCol = 1 WHERE bitCol = 0
```

See also:

- [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)
- [How do you create a yes/no boolean field in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi this one does not work, I tried lots of work. The code take affect, but the value it appears in the table is a blank. I don't know why...

Comment: @JamesChen What is the data type of the `statue` column?

Comment: I set as bit, it appears bit(1) in it

Comment: @JamesChen Drop the `DEFAULT` value of `NULL`.

Comment: Hi I just found although it displayed as blank, the value is still 1! I dont know why, probably system error? Anyway thanks for helping :-)

Comment: @JamesChen Long time ago since this post but could it be that the select shows nothing? Then see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248554/cant-see-mysql-bit-field-value-when-using-select

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL Server, you can set the value of bit fields with `0 and 1`

or

`'true' and 'false'` (yes, using strings)

```
...your_bit_field='false'... => equivalent to 0
```

Comment: Same happened to me, if i do select * from the table, the field looks empty

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is in PHPMyAdmin itself. Some versions do not display the value of bit columns, even though you did set it correctly.