# Procedure always returns empty column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure returns nothing even if the matching data exists in the database.

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `portaldb`.`hasPrivateCloud`$$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `hasPrivateCloud`(in_userId int)
    begin
        if in_userId is not null then
            select (case when ui.privateCloud is null
                    then false
                    else ui.privateCloud
                    end) as hasPrivateCloud from userinfo as ui where ui.userid = in_userId;
        end if;
    end$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

`privateCloud` is a boolean field. If the field is false or where clause is not satisfied, the procedure should return `false` and when where clause is satisfied, it should return the column value. But it always returns an empty column.

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Maybe this following stackoverflow post
[display bit values in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248554/cant-see-mysql-bit-field-value-when-using-select) would help

Answer (score 1):

When the record doesn't exist, nothing is returned. Not, like you assume, a `NULL` record.

You could write it like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT privateCloud FROM userinfo WHERE userid = in_userId)
    SELECT privateCloud FROM userinfo WHERE userid = in_userId;
ELSE
    SELECT 'false';
END IF;
```

When you're so concerned about performance, you can even do

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT @result := privateCloud FROM userinfo WHERE userid = in_userId)
    SELECT @result;
ELSE
    SELECT 'false';
END IF;
```

Comment: Alright. But this will return `true` even when `privateCloud` is false.

Comment: Is there a better way, than running the query two times?

Comment: It's no problem. The result will be in the query cache, when you use it, or the buffer pool.

Comment: @SuhailGupta And I added another possible way, using variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the earlier post. I deleted it. Thanks @fancyPants for pointing that out.

Thought i would add one more suggestion though

```
select (case when ifnull(ui.privateCloud,false)=false
                then 'False'
                else 'True'
                end) as hasPrivateCloud from userinfo as ui where ui.userid= in_userId;
```